# KeyError from customized clean() method in BaseModelFormset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have read over the Forms and Formset Django documentation about 100x.  To make this very clear, this is probably the first time I've ever used super() or tried to overload/inherit from another class (big deal for me.)

What's happening?  I am making a django-model-formset in a view and I am passing it to a template.  The model that the formset is inheriting from happens to be a ManyToMany relationship.  I want these relationships to be unique, so that if my user is creating a form and they accidentally choose the same Object for the ManyToMany, I want it to fail validation.

I believe I have written this custom "BaseModelFormSet" properly (via the documentation) but I am getting a KeyError.  It's telling me that it cannot find cleaned_data['tech'] and I am getting the KeyError on the word 'tech' on the line where I commented below.

The Model:

```
class Tech_Onsite(models.Model):
    tech = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)
    in_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    out_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)

    def total_time(self):
        return self.out_time - self.in_time
```

The customized BaseModelFormSet:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class BaseTechOnsiteFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):

        """ Checks to make sure there are unique techs present """

        super(BaseTechOnsiteFormset, self).clean()

        if any(self.errors):
            # Don't bother validating enless the rest of the form is valid
            return

        techs_present = []

        for form in self.forms:
            tech = form.cleaned_data['tech']  ## KeyError: 'tech' <- 

            if tech in techs_present:
                raise ValidationError("You cannot input multiple times for the same technician.  Please make sure you did not select the same technician twice.")
            techs_present.append(tech)
```

The View: (Summary)

```
## I am instantiating my view with POST data:
tech_onsite_form = tech_onsite_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
## I am receiving an error when the script reaches:
if tech_onsite_form.is_valid():
    ## blah blah blah..
```

Comment: Why don't you just print form.cleaned_data to the log output and see what keys are there? Are you sure there's a `tech` field on your form, and that it's called that?

Comment: @jozzas, I wanted to do this, but it was going to be a drag converting all those forms into a dictionary to pass into the form and emulate all of those processes.  But, I did it and found that I had 4 total forms and 2 of them were blank.  When I iterated over those blank forms looking for 'tech' it was raising a KeyError.  So thank you for encouraging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Django shell to call the forms manually.  I found that I was executing the clean() method on all of the forms returned from the view.  There were 2 filled out with data, and 2 blank.  When my clean() method was iterating through them all, it returned a KeyError when it got to the first blank one.

I fixed my issue by using a try-statement and passing on KeyErrors.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the clean method missing a return statement ? If I remember correctly it should always return the cleaned_data. Also the super call returns the cleaned_data so you should assign it there.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(BaseTechOnsiteFormset, self).clean()
    # use cleaned_data from here to validate your form
    return cleaned_data
```

See: [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more information

Comment: That makes sense.  I assumed it set self.cleaned_data inside of the function instead of returning it.  I followed this example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation), and they did not do what you suggested.  I think it may work differently for formsets?